# Rails: querying records by stored GlobalID string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails (5.2.2) app (Postgres database) with some Models related to different geographies:

```
- districts      (have many sectors)
-- sectors       (have many cells, have one district)
--- cells        (have many villages, have one sector)
---- villages    (have many facilities, have one cell)
----- facilities (have one village)
```

I also have a `Report` Model, which, for context, records the quantity of specific technology distributed in a specific location.

```
#<Report id: nil, date: nil, technology_id: nil, user_id: nil, contract_id: nil, model_gid: nil, distributed: nil, checked: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, people: nil, households: nil>
```

This location can be any of the geography models. So I'm using GlobalID stored as a string in `model_gid` on the `Report` record.

e.g.:

```
#<Report id: 1, ... model_gid: "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64", ...>
```

Then I wrote some scopes that work fine:

```
scope :only_districts,  -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/District/%') }
scope :only_sectors,    -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/Sector/%') }
scope :only_cells,      -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/Cell/%') }
scope :only_villages,   -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/Village/%') }
scope :only_facilities, -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/Facility/%') }
```

I thought this was a good approach because my `report.model` method works:

```
def model
  GlobalID::Locator.locate model_gid
end
```

e.g.:

```
2.4.5 :001 > Report.first.model
  Report Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Village Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 64], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Village id: 64, name: "Ruhanga", cell_id: 11, gis_id: 13080406, latitude: -2.00828333333333, longitude: 30.1708, population: 518, households: 179, created_at: "2019-01-21 22:53:06", updated_at: "2019-01-21 22:53:06">
```

I opted to do this string field instead of a polymorphic association because `GlobalID::Locator` methods can accept strings and parse out the model and ID from it. So why hassle with the association? Maybe this is the fundamental flaw in my thinking?

Because finding records based upon the `model_gid` seems to fail:

```
2.4.5 :045 > Report.all.where(model_gid: Report.first.model_gid)
  Report Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Report Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."model_gid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["model_gid", "--- gid://liters-tracker/Village/64\n"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

(honestly not sure why the SQL is morphed into `"--- gid://liters-tracker/Village/64\n"` and if this is actually my problem)

```
2.4.5 :046 > Report.all.where("model_gid ILIKE ?", Report.first.model_gid)
  Report Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Report Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE (model_gid ILIKE 'gid://liters-tracker/Village/64') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

```
2.4.5 :049 > Report.all.where("model_gid = ?", Report.first.model_gid)
  Report Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Report Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE (model_gid = 'gid://liters-tracker/Village/64') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I'm trying to get this method to work:

```
def self.related_to(record)
  where(model_gid: record.to_global_id.to_s)
end
```

And I really don't understand why it's not working:

```
2.4.5 :010 > Report.first.model_gid
  Report Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64" 
2.4.5 :011 > Village.find(64).to_global_id.to_s
  Village Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 64], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64" 
2.4.5 :012 > Report.first.model_gid == Village.find(64).to_global_id.to_s
  Report Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" ORDER BY "reports"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Village Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 64], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true 
2.4.5 :013 > Report.all.where(model_gid: Village.find(64).to_global_id.to_s)
  Village Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 64], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Report Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."model_gid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["model_gid", "--- gid://liters-tracker/Village/64\n"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

If I mimic the scopes, it does work:

```
def self.related_to(record)
  where('model_gid ILIKE ?', "%#{record.to_global_id.to_s}%")
end
```

But, in the example records I've been showing, this would match Village #64 and Village #640, so it's not a good solution.

**UPDATE**

1. I thought maybe the special characters were throwing things off. But things work as expected when I use another string column on another Model:

```
2.4.5 :052 > Village.first.update(name: "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64")
  Village Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" ORDER BY "villages"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Cell Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cells".* FROM "cells" WHERE "cells"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Village Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."gis_id" = $1 AND "villages"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3  [["gis_id", 11070101], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Village Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "villages" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "villages"."id" = $3  [["name", "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64"], ["updated_at", "2019-07-06 22:16:38.585563"], ["id", 1]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
2.4.5 :053 > Village.where(name: "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64")
  Village Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "villages".* FROM "villages" WHERE "villages"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Village id: 1, name: "gid://liters-tracker/Village/64", cell_id: 1, gis_id: 11070101, latitude: -2.054922, longitude: 30.0912883, population: 513, households: 110, created_at: "2019-01-21 22:53:04", updated_at: "2019-07-06 22:16:38">]>
```

2. I thought maybe I needed an index on the `Report.model_gid` field. But it hasn't made a difference.

```
class AddModelGidIndexToReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_index :reports, :model_gid
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 2** 
(this is based upon my own provided 'answer', but since it's a question, I put it here)

@MichaelChaney:

Just so I'm clear, are you suggesting something like this:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :technology, inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :user,       inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :contract,   inverse_of: :reports
  enum geography: { district: 'district', sector: 'sector', cell: 'cell', village: 'village', facility: 'facility' }
```

At this point, should I just add a `geography_id` integer column and stop using GlobalID?

What about just going polymorphic instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closing the record, I switched to a polymorphic association. Probably not quite as fast as the Enum solution that @MichaelChaney suggests in the comments on the previous answer, but fast enough for my in-house app and creates an association known to my app.

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :technology, inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :user,       inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :contract,   inverse_of: :reports
  # serialize :model_gid  #<-- this was real bad as @MichaelChaney points out
  # enum geography: { district: 'district', sector: 'sector', cell: 'cell', village: 'village', facility: 'facility' }  #<-- this is probably the fastest option
  belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true  #<-- this is probably the middle ground, as the :reportable_id and :reportable_type columns are indexed together
```

And this was partnered with the following on all my Geography models, e.g.:

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :village, inverse_of: :facilities
  has_one :cell, through: :village, inverse_of: :facilities
  has_one :sector, through: :cell, inverse_of: :facilities
  has_one :district, through: :sector, inverse_of: :facilities
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable, inverse_of: :reportable  #<-- tadaa
```

So now I don't even need my initial method as I can compare the results of `reports.reportable` with the record I have to see if they are associated.

The lesson I learned: in the early stages, I need to think more about RdBMS and what associations I'll care a lot about so I don't try doing dumb Regex searches across my dB.

The other lesson: keep better notes in my code base, so when I change strategies I can correctly un-wind things I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. This is a face-palm moment.

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :technology, inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :user,       inverse_of: :reports
  belongs_to :contract,   inverse_of: :reports
  serialize :model_gid

  scope :only_districts,  -> { where('model_gid ILIKE ?', '%/District/%') }
  ...
```

`Report.model_gid` is serialized, which I did before I discovered GlobalID. I think I was planning to save some key-value hash like `{model: 'Village', id: '64'}`.

Now to figure out how to un-serialize a column.

Comment: This whole thing is a face-palm moment.  What you're trying could work, but every single query involves a table scan along with a regexp match on every single row.  I cannot express in words how terrible of an idea this is.  Add a column to your report table to specify this type so that it can be directly queried.  You probably just want to use some sort of enum.  This link explains it: `https://dev.to/amplifr/postgres-enums-with-rails-4ld0`.  Please note that I'm not answering your question because you really need to fundamentally change your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MichaelChaney. I updated the question and would appreciate a response. I'm very interested in the fundamental change to the approach, but not sure I'm actually understanding it.